# Creating a socket.io connection to a different host. Works in CRA dev build but not in production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, feathersjs

The CRA is being served from https://moto.
It is using something called feathers.js which has a wrapper for the socket.io-client, @feathersjs/socketio-client.
It is configured like this:

```
const srv = feathers();
srv.configure(socketio(io('https://motorest')));
```

Issue:
When I run, npm start, and launch a browser, in the network tab of dev tools I can see the GET calls to motorest and everything works ok.
When I serve the production build from serve -s build or http-server, I can see the GET calls are to moto instead of motorest.
I guess there is some optimization going on in, npm run build, that replaces motorest with the host name the CRA is being served from.

I would appreciate any help you could provide. Thank you.

Comment: Is moto and motorest same domain?

Comment: moto and motorest are on our company's internal network.  We don't use the domain portion to access them.

Comment: Thank you, Fide. I appreciate your time.

Comment: You still have to differentiate it - is the request done to the same domain - though local? Can you place here an example? 
Why I'm asking: request of page that originates in A can be done only to the same origin - due to CSRF protection. If I am creating socket connection, always on same domain, and I differentiate it with parameter in URL - like mydomain.com - is web page, mydomain.com/socket is socket address.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much, Fide.  The problem was I did not realize that there must be a domain in the connection string.